# Same volume a two different parallelepiped

Tags: linear-algebra

The volume of a parallelepiped defined by the vectors $$w, u, \text{ and }v, \text{ where } w=u \times v$$ is computed using:
$$V = w \cdot (u \times v)$$

However, if the parallelepiped is defined by the vectors $$w-u, u, \text{ and }v, \text{ where (still) } w=u \times v$$ instead, the volume remains the same.

I can verify this numerically - but I would like to do it mathematically. How?

Comment: It is a shearing, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_mapping, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just plug into your volume formula you have $V=(w-u)\cdot (u \times v)$.  The dot product is distributive, so $V=w \cdot (u \times v)-u \cdot (u \times v)$.  The cross product is perpendicular to the vectors that comprise it, so the last dot product is zero and we get $V=w\cdot (u \times v)$ as desired.  We don't need the assumption that $w = u \times v$.  It works for any $u,v,w$

Answer (score 1):

Well, those two parallelepipeds have same bases (parallelogram spanned with $u$ and $v$) and same altitudes.